# Shader for solid color for each triangle of plane geometry

Tags: three.js, shader, webgl

I have been learning webgl from webglfundamentals where I came across a simple shader example where you can paint triangles with solid color. Here is link to [tutorial](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-how-it-works.html) and original [demo](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/webgl-2d-rectangle-with-2-colors.html).

I tried to create same effect in three js using plane geometry but I can't manage achieve solid color shader. When I use almost same setup in Three js, I get more like gradient effect. What am I doing wrong here? (I am noticing that my shader isn't consistent either as it renders differently on refresh) Also, is there place to learn shaders specifically for three js?

```js
    var vShader = ` 
    precision mediump float;
    precision mediump int;
    
    attribute vec4 a_color;
    varying vec4 vColor;
    
    void main()    {
    
      
    
      gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
      vColor = a_color;
    }`;
    
    var fShader = ` precision mediump float;
    precision mediump int;
    
    varying vec4 vColor;
    
    void main()    {
    
      vec4 color = vec4( vColor );
      gl_FragColor = vColor;
    
    }`;
    
    var row = 1;
    var col = 1;
    var w = 600;
    var h = 400;
    
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, w / h, 0.1, 100);
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    camera.position.z = 5;
    
    var viewSize = getViewSize(camera);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    renderer.setSize(w, h);
    
    
    
    var geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(viewSize.width, viewSize.height, col, row);
    
    
    var color = new THREE.Color();
    const blossomPalette = [0xff0000, 0xff0000, 0xff0000, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff];
    var colors = new Float32Array(4 * 2 * 3 * col * row);
    for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        color.setHex(blossomPalette[Math.floor(Math.random() * blossomPalette.length)]);
        color.toArray(colors, i * 3);
    }
    geometry.setAttribute('a_color', new THREE.BufferAttribute(colors, 4, false));
    
    var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
        vertexShader: vShader,
        fragmentShader: fShader,
        transparent: true,
        blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending,
        depthTest: false,
        vertexColors: true,
        flatShading: true
    });
    
    var plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    
    scene.add(plane);
    
    function animate() {
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
        requestAnimationFrame(animate)
    
    }
    animate();
    
    
    function getViewSize(camera) {
        var fovInRadians = (camera.fov * Math.PI) / 180;
        var height = Math.abs(camera.position.z * Math.tan(fovInRadians / 2) * 2);
        return {
            width: height * camera.aspect,
            height: height
        }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r122/build/three.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PlaneBufferGeometry` in three.js is using [indexed vertices](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-indexed-vertices.html) to share vertices so there are only 4 vertices and then 6 indices to use those 4 vertices to make 2 triangles. That means you can't give each triangle different solid colors because they share 2 vertices and a vertex can only have 1 color.

Further, the code is choosing random colors for each vertex so even if you you used 6 vertices so that the 2 triangles didn't share any you still wouldn't get [the result you linked to](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/webgl-2d-rectangle-with-2-colors.html), instead you'd get [this result](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/webgl-2d-rectangle-with-random-colors.html) which is further down the page on the same tutorial.

Finally the code is only generating 3 floats per color so you need to set the number of components for the color attribute to 3 instead of 4

If you want to repeat the webgl sample you'll need to provide your own 6 vertices.

```js
var vShader = ` 
    precision mediump float;
    precision mediump int;
    
    attribute vec4 a_color;
    varying vec4 vColor;
    
    void main()    {
    
      
    
      gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
      vColor = a_color;
    }`;
    
    var fShader = ` precision mediump float;
    precision mediump int;
    
    varying vec4 vColor;
    
    void main()    {
    
      vec4 color = vec4( vColor );
      gl_FragColor = vColor;
    
    }`;
    
    var row = 1;
    var col = 1;
    var w = 600;
    var h = 400;
    
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, w / h, 0.1, 100);
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    camera.position.z = 5;
    
    var viewSize = getViewSize(camera);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    renderer.setSize(w, h);
    
    
    
    var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
    var x = viewSize.width / 2;
    var y = viewSize.height / 2;
    var positions = new Float32Array([
       -x, -y, 0,
        x, -y, 0,
       -x,  y, 0,
       -x,  y, 0,
        x, -y, 0,
        x,  y, 0,
    ]);
    geometry.setAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(positions, 3, false));
    
    var color = new THREE.Color();
    const blossomPalette = [
       0xff0000, 0xff0000, 0xff0000,
       0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff,
     ];
    var colors = new Float32Array(2 * 3 * 3 * col * row);
    for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        color.setHex(blossomPalette[i]);
        color.toArray(colors, i * 3);
    }
    geometry.setAttribute('a_color', new THREE.BufferAttribute(colors, 3, false));
    
    var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
        vertexShader: vShader,
        fragmentShader: fShader,
        transparent: true,
        blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending,
        depthTest: false,
        vertexColors: true,
        flatShading: true
    });
    
    var plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    
    scene.add(plane);
    
    function animate() {
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
        requestAnimationFrame(animate)
    
    }
    animate();
    
    
    function getViewSize(camera) {
        var fovInRadians = (camera.fov * Math.PI) / 180;
        var height = Math.abs(camera.position.z * Math.tan(fovInRadians / 2) * 2);
        return {
            width: height * camera.aspect,
            height: height
        }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r122/build/three.min.js"></script>
```

See [this article](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-custom-buffergeometry.html)